# ASP.NET MVC Change Table Row Attributes From C# Controller Based on Data in Model

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-5

I found similar questions, but they were with datagrids, and I'm using a table class.  I want to separate the logic I use to change attributes of the rows I create in a View, and put the logic in the Controller.
This is so I can unit test my logic.  Currently this is how I'm sending the data to the View

```
public ViewResult Index()
    {
        var todoes = repository.GetAll();
        return View(todoes);
    }
```

This is how I'm currently building the table, and coloring the text for overdue tasks.

```
   @foreach (var item in Model)
   {
      <tr>
         <td>
           <li class="@(item.Deadline.Date < DateTime.Today && !item.Completed ? "overdue" : "notoverdue")">
               @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TaskName)
           </li>
         </td>
         <td>
           @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Deadline)
         </td>
         <td>
           @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Completed)
        </td>
        <td>
           @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Moredetails)
        </td>
        <td>
          @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {id = item.TodoId}) |
          @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new {id = item.TodoId}) |
          @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new {id = item.TodoId})
        </td>
    </tr>
  }

<style type="text/css">
    li.overdue {
        color: lightcoral;
     }

     li.notoverdue {
        color: black;
     }
</style>
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: your question is a little unclear. are you saying you want to move the logic for assigning the overdue / notoverdue attributes to the table? if so, this logic belongs in the view as it deals with how the data is displayed and i would leave it there

Comment: You make a good point, but I think that it is part of the business logic of the feature. However I still need to take a tutorial on TDD with views, and perhaps I'll learn how to test the logic in a view.

Comment: There isn't meant to be any logic in the views (or as little as possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always put the logic that you have in your view on the actual object model and then use this in your view, for example:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string CssClass
    {
        get
        {
            return Deadline.Date < DateTime.Today && !Completed ? "overdue" : "notoverdue";
        }
    }
}
```

Then use this property in your view:

```
<li class="@item.CssClass" ..... />
```

Comment: Thank you, but I can't unit test that logic, which is the goal of refactoring the overdue feature.

Comment: You can test this on an object something like `Assert.Equals(myList[0].CssClass, "overdue");`

Comment: Thank you Ric, I'm going to implement that fix, and mark this as solved.  Thank you for your time.